# Pop List of elements from a nested list of elements

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

```
X = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], [6, 0], [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [7, 0], [7, 1], [7, 2], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9], [8, 0], [8, 1], [8, 2], [8, 3], [8, 4], [8, 5], [8, 6], [8, 7], [8, 8], [8, 9], [9, 0], [9, 1], [9, 2], [9, 3], [9, 4], [9, 5], [9, 6], [9, 7], [9, 8], [9, 9]]

Y = [[9, 3], [9, 1], [5, 5], [7, 9], [0, 9], [4, 2], [7, 6], [5, 3], [6, 2], [8, 4], [5, 8], [4, 9], [7, 4], [3, 5], [6, 0], [5, 6], [6, 8], [4, 0], [6, 1], [8, 2], [7, 5], [9, 4], [9, 8], [9, 5], [6, 4]]

Z = []
```

How to get the list of elements from x to z where all the elements from y in x are removed

Comment: what is your desried output and but have you tried so far??

Comment: `Z = [e for e in X if e not in Y]`?

Comment: Can you give a short example of what the output should look like?

Answer (score 0):

- Turn X and Y into sets of tuples instead of lists of lists
- Z will be the difference of x and y.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference

Answer (score 0):

You can do a list comprehension for creating `Z`:

```
Z=[e for e in X if e not in Y]
```

Then do another list comprehension with a slice assignment to 'remove' the elements from the first step:

```
X[:]=[e for e in X if e not in Z]
```